# Laravel 7 authentication attempt

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

From Laravel 7.x documentation, I'm trying to create a manual authentication for my application. The documentation shows as following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```

I have my own user's table:

```
sys_users
==========
user_acc character varying(20) NOT NULL, -- Primary Key
full_name character varying(300) NOT NULL,
is_suspended boolean DEFAULT FALSE,
CONSTRAINT PK_SysUsers PRIMARY KEY (user_acc),
```

To login, the user need to enter the following data:

- Username
- Password
- Module to access

I tried to customize the controller a bit (not completed yet):

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
        
        $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password', 'module');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect()->route($request->module);
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to add to the customized code above is: (i) checking if the username is exist in the table by querying the `sys_users` table, (ii) checking the password using POP3 (I already prepared the `phpmailer` library and the code), and (iii) checking if the user has access to those module by querying another table that I had prepared.

The problem is:

1. I don't know **WHERE** to put all of that code. If possible, I wanted to put them inside the `Auth` class' `attempt` method, but I can't seem to find the supposed method. The documentation is very lacking and did not provide a detailed explanation.
2. **IF** somehow it is impossible to modify the `attempt` method in `Auth` class, how should I proceed with the authentication process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking to do is implement your own [user provider](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#adding-custom-guards) to verify your users credentials using an external POP3 email system.

I don't believe you need to customize your Guard, as I am assuming you still would like the `StatefulGuard` of the default `SessionGuard` which will check and store information about the state of authentication in the session.

I think you likely want all other default behavior, aside from how you are validating the credentials provided.

Perhaps in the `./app/Providers/` folder you can create:

PopThreeUserProvider.php

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as UserContract;

class PopThreeUserProvider extends EloquentUserProvider
{
    /**
     * Validate a user against the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
    {
        // Implement your pop3 authentication here, I have left the default code
        // for the Eloquent provider below
        $plain = $credentials['password'];

        return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
    }
}
```

Now in your `./app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php`

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    ...

    /**
     * Register any application authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        ...

        Auth::provider('pop3', function ($app, array $config) {
            return new PopThreeUserProvider($app->make('hash'), $config['model']);
        });

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Now in your `config/auth.php`:

```
    ...

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'pop3',
        ],
    ],

    ...
```

Of course this all assumes you have:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'sys_users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_acc';
    protected $incrementing = false;
    ...
```

Comment: For the `config/auth.php`, should i replace the default code: `'driver' => 'eloquent', 'model' => App\User::class,`?

Comment: You can do as I did above, or create your on provider, and change the web guard to use it. See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#adding-custom-guards