# How can I login manually with API between two laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel

I’ve two Laravel based projects and I want to login with API which the first project provides and use this authentication in the second project.

in the `LoginController` in second project:

```php
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $login_response = Http::post('{first_project_login_api}', [
            'data' => [
                "email"     => $request->input('email'),
                "password"  => $request->input('password')
            ]
        ]);

        if ($this->attemptLogin($login_response)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }
    }

protected function attemptLogin(Response $response)
    {
        return $response->object()->status === 200;
    }
```

In the second project, I don't need to database because I want to authentication in the first project but does not seems to be possible!

actually I need to know how to overwrite `attemptLogin()` function in `LoginController`.

It would be highly appreciated if anyone can advise me!

Comment: One option is to create your own UserProvider, and then put the logic of authenticating with your other project in the validateCredentials method. See my answer for a similar question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63070909/1978311).

Comment: Are you fixed it please?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using login between application, i would use `API` keys. The easiest way to get started is to use simple [API Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication#passing-tokens-in-requests).

First create migrations for the user table.

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->string('api_token', 80)->after('password')
        ->unique()
        ->nullable()
        ->default(null);
});
```

To get keys, set them on the user either in Tinker, command or creation.

```
$user->api_token = Str::random(60);
$user->save();
```

Protect your API routes with a middleware.

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function() {
    // your routes
});
```

Calling your api is as simply as.

```
response = $client->request('POST', $yourRoute, [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $yourToken,
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
    ],
]);
```

This is a fairly basic setup, for production or moving forward you should look into [Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum) or [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport). This is just a good start, from where i feel you are based on your question.